# Cannot find view for ViewModel, even though SelectedAssembly is overridden

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

For some reason I am getting the `Cannot find view for CaliburnPractice.ViewModel` error. I've looked at some of the answers on here for this but none of them have worked for me. I've put the view and viewmodel into separate named folders and I've already overridden the SelectedAssembly method. What is going on? See my code below.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnPractice
{
    public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
   {

   }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="CaliburnPractice.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CaliburnPractice"
         >
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

**PracticeView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnPractice.PracticeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Width="300" Height="300" Background="LightBlue">

</Grid>
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CaliburnPractice
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender,         System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(sender, e);
            DisplayRootViewFor<ViewModel>();
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Assembly>     SelectAssemblies()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is looking for View, where your viewmodel is named ViewModel...the view you have listed is PracticeView...

ShellView -> ShellViewModel

MainView -> MainViewModel etc....

therefore PracticeView -> PracticeViewModel  would get resolved....

SelectedAssembly is used in the case of separate views/viewmodels in different DLLs

Unless you aren't including anything we might need to know...

Comment: This is super important. I had all my views/viewmodels set up perfectly and all. But because my view model had a slightly different name than the view (like adding one word to it) Caliburn couldn't find it. This fixed my issue!